# Test for asciidoc failed when installing tinyproxy

Tags: linux

I want to install tinyproxy
https://banu.com/tinyproxy/

when I `cd` into the directory and run `make`
I get

```
checking for a2x... no
configure: error: Test for asciidoc failed. See the file 'INSTALL' for help.
```

then I want to install asciidoc
I get

```
[root@dd tinyproxy-1.8.3]yum install asciidoc
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package asciidoc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

how to deal with this?
thanks

Comment: `sudo yum install asciidoc` worked for me on CentOS

Answer (score 4):

If asciidoc is not in your linux distribution or you are not root. you have to install it manually. download the asciidoc tarball from http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/ and do the usual:

```
  configure --prefix=${HOME} && make && make install
```

Then make sure that ${HOME}/bin is in your PATH, e.g. by running
  export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin

The configure script of tinyproxy will check if a2x is somewhere in your PATH. If it can't find it, you won't get it to compile.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care the docs of tinyproxy, just remove the `docs` subdirectory from the `SUBDIRS` variable in Makefile and then `make`.

This will skip the doc generating target when calling `make`, so there is no need to install `a2x`.

Comment: for me make failed even though asciidoc was installed. This was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu 13, so apt-get install asciidoc worked for me, you might wanna check your yum repositories if 
"yum install asciidoc" shows "No package asciidoc available."

Meanwhile checkout official site for asciidoc (make sure you look at the pre-requisits)
http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the ruby version of the project? `sudo yum install rubygem-asciidoctor`

Other options available to install the gem are described here: http://asciidoctor.org/

The advantage of this is that most gems only have other gems as dependencies, in most cases they don't have a c library as a dependency so you won't run into issues when installing, in any case yum should be able to figure it out.